# RotatingFileHandler does not continue logging after error encountered

Tags: python, logging

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/handlers.py", line 76, in emit
    if self.shouldRollover(record):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/handlers.py", line 150, in       shouldRollover
     self.stream.seek(0, 2)  #due to non-posix-compliant Windows feature
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I have a line in my script:

```
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(cfg_obj.log_file,maxBytes = maxlog_size, backupCount = 10)
```

It runs fine when there are no error messages. But when there's an error log, the logs after the error are not written to the file unless the process is restarted. We do not want to restart the process every time there is an error. 
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use a configuration file. The configuration code below "logging.conf" has different handlers and formatters just as example:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, rotatingFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter, extendedFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler, rotatingFileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_rotatingFileHandler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=extendedFormatter
args=('path/logs_file.log', 'a', 2000000, 1000)


[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=

[formatter_extendedFormatter]
format= %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s() %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Now how to use it "main.py":

```
import logging.config

# LOGGER
logging.config.fileConfig('path_to_conf_file/logging.conf')
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('root')
try:
    LOGGER.debug("Debug message...")
    LOGGER.info("Info message...")   
except Exception as e:    
    LOGGER.exception(e)
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Can you please specify how using a config file would be better?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why the file gets closed when error log is encountered and the future logs are not written to it.

Comment: First of all scalability. Anyone without (programming / python) knowledge can add features or modify the configuration file without breaking the whole application. It makes easy to configure and setup you logging mechanism. You can set it up in you python code but is not as clean as having an easy "configurable" file. However It's up to you how to do it. ;-)

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll try making that change but is it a bug in the python handler to lock the log file after an error log is encountered?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe the error it's not being handle correctly and the process just exit without log it. Try the example I posted and let me know. Check the file handler arguments, the file will be opened  in 'a' (append) mode.